# How to check if there intersection in list of pairs?

Tags: scala, collections

We have a list of pairs e.g. as follows

```
val listPairs = List(("a", "a"), ("b", "a"), ("d", "d"), ("a", "c"))
```

I want to find if there exist `i != j` such that

```
listPairs(i)._1 = listPairs(j)._2
```

and print the first such `i, j` found.

So for `listPairs` there definitely is `i = 0, j = 1`

The only way I could find by myself is to simply traverse the list for each index `i, j, i < j` and do the comparison. But that's an ugly nested loop with mutable variables.

Can anyone suggest a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for-comprehension` with a `guard` as shown below:

```
val listPairs = List(("a", "a"), ("b", "a"), ("d", "d"), ("a", "c"))

val sz = listPairs.size

for {
  i <- (0 until sz)
  j <- (0 until sz)
  if i != j && listPairs(i)._1 == listPairs(j)._2
} yield (i, j)
// res1: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Int, Int)] = Vector((0,1), (3,0), (3,1))
```

In case only matches with i < j are wanted:

```
for {
  i <- (0 until sz)
  j <- (i+1 until sz)
  if listPairs(i)._1 == listPairs(j)._2
} yield (i, j)
// res2: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Int, Int)] = Vector((0,1))
```

Comment: This does works, but the approach you used is very _inefficient_: `size` of a list is **O(N)** and `apply` a list by index  is **O(I)**.

Comment: You're right Luis.  If performance is the priority, I would probably advise against using a `List` and resort to using an `Array` for more efficient indexing and iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly modified from Leo's answer, I used `zipWithIndex` to avoid accessing the lists by index.

```
def checkIntersections[T](pairs: List[(T, T)]): List[(Int, Int)] = {
  val pairsWithIndex = pairs.zipWithIndex

  val result = for {
    ((a, _), i) <- pairsWithIndex
    ((_, b), j) <- pairsWithIndex
    if i != j && a == b
  } yield (i, j)

  result.toList
}

checkIntersections(List(("a", "a"), ("b", "a"), ("d", "d"), ("a", "c")))
// res0: List[(Int, Int)] = List((0,1), (3,0), (3,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using tail recursion

```
val listPairs = List(("a", "a"), ("b", "c"), ("d", "d"), ("y", "a"))
def res(lst: List[(String,String)], count: Int): Option[(Int,Int)] = {
if (lst.isEmpty) return None
lst.tail.indexWhere(_._2 == lst.head._1) match {
  case -1 => res(lst.tail, count+1)
  case a: Int => Some((count,count+a+1))
}
}
println(res(listPairs, 0))
```

output: Some((0,3))